# How to setup Visual Studio Python Environment with EventGhost

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio's Python Environment so I can write some EventGhost plugins. EventGhost has it's own Python environment installed in it's directory, but when I try to setup the environment in Visual Studio the Intellisense DB does not bring in any packages.

**EventGhost's Directory:**

[image: ![EventGhost's Directory]

**Contents of Lib:**

[image]

I'm simply trying to get Intellisense DB to populate with EventGhost's eg module (located in the eg directory of the application). Currently I just get "unknown type" for everything:

[image]

**My Python Environment Setup in VS:**

[image]

Comment: What does the contents of "Lib" look like? Is it the same as for a regular Python install, or is there just a single .zip there?

Comment: Also, judging by your screenshot, `eg`is not under `Lib` (i.e. it's not part of the standard library). Which means that for PTVS to locate it, you'll need to add EventGhost's top level directory - the one that contains `eg` - to the Search Path of your project to get completions for that particular package.

Comment: @PavelMinaev I added a screen shot of the lib dir

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Python-Environments is a tutorial on setting up Python environments for VS. It includes a way to check which packages Intellisense sees and force it to rescan the path.

Specifically, I suspect you need to change "library path" to `<...>\lib26`.

Comment: FWIW, the new link to that documentation page is https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/python/python-environments. The home page for Python in Visual Studio is https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/python/python-in-visual-studio.